# Erlang, lists: find element with maximum defined by a fun

Tags: list, erlang

The `lists` module provides a function to find the maximum of a list, `lists:max(List)`.

Is there a function like `lists:maxfun(Fun, List)`? The given fun should be used for all Elements and `maxfun` should give this Element back instead of the value. For example:

```
Fun gets [X,Y] and calcs X+Y
lists:maxfun(Fun,[[1,1],[1,2]]} -> [1,2].
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use for example this trick:

```
1> F=fun([X,Y]) -> X+Y end.                                  
#Fun<erl_eval.6.13229925>
2> element(2, lists:max([ {F(X), X} || X <- [[1,1],[1,2]]])).
[1,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use lists:foldl for it, something like this:

```
lists:foldl(fun([X1,Y1],[X2,Y2]) when X1 + Y1 > X2 + Y2 ->
                [X1,Y1];
               (_, Acc) ->
                 Acc
            end, [0,0], ListOfLists).
```

Comment: If you use the first element of the list as the initial accumulator then you will always have a good initial value.